Why does QR1173 take such an indirect route?
QR1173 from RUH to DOH takes a very indirect route (at least to my untrained eye):

What is the reason for that? A direct route would be entirely on KSA and Qatar territory where there are no particular risks (as in avoiding a war zone).

It's definitely not a Mercator map distortion.
It could be the threat created by Houthi militia launching missiles and drones from Yemen, targeting Israel. Over the last years there has been strikes in the south of Jeddah FIR (OEJD). From Conflict Zone & Risk Database:

Missiles should fly on the western part of KSA, however there are also navy ships of several countries intercepting these weapons from the south part of the Red Sea, these interceptions could lead to objects falling in southern KSA. In addition Houtis have also targeted airports in KSA prior to the Gaza strip conflict.
This FIR has active warnings (more here) for the south:

The primary risk is from Houthi drone and missile attacks on Israel, shipping in the Red Zea, and prior attempts on airports across the country, but particularly in the south.

but also in other areas:

Nov 2024: Red Sea Conflict Zone risk. Saudi lies between Yemen and Israel, and there have been in excess of 220 missiles and drones fired across Saudi Arabia in the last 12 months. A missile intercept incident near Jeddah on Nov 3 (observed at close proximity by transiting air crew) has highlighted the risk to civil aviation, and has made it clear that this area is an extension of the Israeli conflict.

From FAA Saudi Arabia/Yemen: Houthi UAS Attack in Riyadh:

On 10 March 2022, Yemen-based Houthi forces launched an attack against an Aramco oil refinery in Riyadh, Saudi Arabia, utilizing multiple unmanned aircraft systems (UAS), which caused a small fire. No major damage or casualties were reported. The most recent prior long range attack into Saudi Arabia occurred on 3 January 2022 near Taif.

KSA issued the Emergency Security Control of Air traffic (ESCAT) procedures in April 2022, they are still active. Several routes are described. I haven't drawn the routes on a map, but I guess the one described in your question is part of the selection.

Thank you. The location of Riyadh (and its east area) is not really anywhere in the conflict area but your explanation makes a lot of sense. Better worry then sorry, I guess. Thanks again.
